# Where to place navigation menu - above or below featured image rotator?

Tags: gui-design

I'm working on a car leasing website, and trying to place the navigation correctly. In my opinion, it seems better to follow the 'typical' website layout, where the navigation is either inline or directly below the logo. As outlined here:

[Standard layout](https://wireframe.cc/HOSTJg)

However, I have another party that wishes the navigation to be below several elements on the webpage (Below the logo, an image slider/rotator, and brand logos):

[Proposed Layout](https://wireframe.cc/di56P9)

The wireframe doesn't look terrible, but in mockups with many elements on the page, it seems that the navgation could get lost somewhere in the mix. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if the navigation is critical to task completion. Will the navigation always reside beneath featured content or only on this page? It isn't unheard of to put the navigation below featured content (example: www.taylorguitars.com) with the navigation sticking as the user scrolls. I've observed negative reactions to this approach on a client website because users went directly to the navigation to find specific content. As a result, the unusual placement was disorienting. However, if they were more inclined to use content as navigation then the unusual placement would have been OK; navigation for pivoting to a new category or as an option when lost in the site structure.

If users are in discovery mode, the unusual placement can work. If users are completing very specific tasks or known item seeking then your 2nd approach may throw them off. Is it a little bit of both? Weigh the pro/cons of each option.

Good luck!

Comment: Another example can be found here: http://www.fourseasons.com/newyork/

Comment: This would more or less be the homepage. Most of the functionality will be within a search feature (searching for cars, etc)... so a lot of the emphasis will be based on that. However, the basic needs of the site (contact, about, whatever) still needs to be apparent, and I feel like the main navigation gets lost under featured content... but that's just my personal take, which is most likely biased towards what I normally see.